# Cannot leave Kephallonia, even though the game has been fully downloaded

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I'm having trouble leaving Kephallonia.

Apparently, before I leave, I have to finish installing the game, so I did that: I literally explored all of Kephallonia while waiting for the game to finish downloading. When it finally did I went back to Barnabas ready to set sail.
But when I clicked "Let's go", the same message popped up saying "*You cannot leave the island of Kephallonia until the game is filled installed*". However, the game *is* fully installed, I literally waited for it to finish.

I have spent the past 3 or 4 hours restarting my PS4, I've restored the database, checked the internet connection - I did everything to try and fix the issue but that message keeps popping up every time I try to leave the island.

I even deleted the game and reinstalled it, and this time I waited for the game to fully download before playing, but it still didn't work.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade. *How* do you know the game has been fully installed?

Comment: Did you get a PS4 notification that it was installed? Also there was a big update recently that necessitates a full re-download, maybe it's doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you fully restart your PS4 or go to sleep mode and back? (there is a major difference)

Also did you try closing the application? Like if you press the PS button for a while, go to applications, and close Assassins Creed? I'm not sure rebooting the PS4 actually closes the app or it just dumps it on the HDD and restarts from where it was (thus not resetting the game) That should restart Assassins Creed from scratch and make sure that check is remade.

For a reset to 'count' I would say you need to have seen all the warnings and stuff and then landed back on the main menu. If you boot the game and it is already in the game with you running around, it didn't reset.

You should also go to your notifications and make sure the content is downloaded and installed. The install might have crashed or hanged and that is what is causing you to not have the content.

And, if nothing works, the nuclear option, delete the game fully off your PS4 and reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: he already mentioned that he tried deleting it and reinstalling it.

Comment: Damn it missed that part. If he did so (and correctly) its weird AF. Like I could see he deleted his savefile and tought it was the game, but thats a stretch.

Comment: easy to do, np =).    I could see that happening, whenever anything has to do with game files, anything is possible.